# Highlight search resuls with string part

Tags: php, preg-replace

i am using the code below to highlight the search results:

```
$text = preg_replace("/\b($word)\b/i", '<span class="highlight_word">\1</span>', $text);
```

and its working fine.

But the preg_replace return the whole string and highlight the words that match.

I need to get a part of the string and only the whole string.

A scenario is to get 100 chars before and 100 chars after the first match. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want 100 characters before and after then just change your regex from`/\b($word)\b/i`
to `/^.*?(.{0,100})\b($word)\b(.{0,100}).*?$/i`

Then change your replacement to `\1<span class="highlight_word">\2</span>\3`

And altogether:
`$text = preg_replace("/^.*?(.{0,100})\b($word)\b(.{0,100}).*?$/i", '\1<span class="highlight_word">\2</span>\3', $text);`

Edit: Updated after poster comment. That should do what you want.

Edit2:  The regex would fail if there weren't 100 characters on either side.  This one will work regardless of whether there are 100 characters before/after the word now.  If there are less than 100 characters it will match them all.

Edit3: Updated answer after poster comment.

Comment: With this modification it highlight all the string but i want to highlight only the $word and have 100 before and after but not highlighted.Thanks for your response

Comment: Updated original answer to better fit what you wanted.

Comment: It highlights the $word only but returns the whole text.It does not return 100 before and after.I even change to {0,1} to see what happens but still returns the whole $text

Comment: Updated the answer to be what you wanted.